# optimizing multiple try except code for web scraping

Tags: python

I have a web scraping script where, due to many reasons, some codes "break" if not finding the information as expected. I am handling it with multiple "try/except" blocks.

```
        asin = item.get('data-asin')
        title = item.find_all('span',{'class' : 'a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal'})[0].get_text()   

        try: 
            label = item.find_all('span',{'aria-label' : 'Escolha da Amazon'})[0].get('aria-label')
        except IndexError :
            label = None
            
        try:
            current_whole_price = item.find_all('span', {'class' : 'a-price'})[0].find('span', {'class' : 'a-price-whole'}).get_text().replace(',','').replace('.','')
        except:
            current_whole_price = '0'
        
        try : 
            current_fraction_price = item.find_all('span', {'class' : 'a-price'})[0].find('span', {'class' : 'a-price-fraction'}).get_text() 
        except : 
            current_fraction_price = '0'
        current_price = float(current_whole_price+'.'+current_fraction_price)

        try : 
            rating_info = item.find('div', {'class':'a-row a-size-small'}).get_text()
            rating = float(rating_info[:3].replace(',','.'))
            rating_count = int(re.findall(r'\d+', rating_info)[-1])
        except : 
            rating =  None
            rating_count = None

        try:
            ad = True if (item.find_all('span', {'class' : 'a-color-secondary'})[0].get_text() == 'Patrocinado') else False
        except IndexError:
            ad = False
        
        _ = {'productId' : itemId,
            'asin' : asin,
            'opt_label' : label,
            #"ad": True if (item.find_all('span', {'class' : 'a-color-secondary'})[0].get_text() == 'Patrocinado') else False ,
            "ad": ad,
            'title' : title,
            'current_price' : current_price,
            'url':f'https://www.amazon.com.br/dp/{asin}',
            'rating' : rating,
            'rating_count' : rating_count,
            }
```

But, looking at my code, you can see that many of the "try/except" are similar.
I wonder if I could use some kind of function where I just pass the "item", the "desired selector" and the "failsafe value" to return if it goes wrong.

I intend to make my code simpler and smaller. I take any tips!

Regards!

Comment: What you've described is a very practical way to do it/  What have you attempted?

Comment: I could get a function to work as I though! Lol. I saw some logic, but couldn't implement it.

Comment: why not use find on all those find_all which you are already going to 0 index?

Comment: Good code.  One remark though:  try to always use exception criteria on the excepts (see answer).  As written you *might* even hide a compilation error like a missed parenthesis with a bare except.  I know because I lost hours once on just this type of only-one-error code (a compilation error might break out but it’s a simple example to give).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can create a function to handle the repetitive try/except blocks, but you have to find a common way to get your fields, then it might be something like:

```py
def get_element(item, selector, attribute, failsafe_value=None):
    try:
        element = item.find(selector).get(attribute)
        return element if element else failsafe_value
    except (AttributeError, IndexError):
        return failsafe_value
```

Comment: How do I pass the parameter to the selector, for example "('span',{'class' : 'a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal'})" as It is no a string.

Comment: For those who might have the same question, I am using selector as a tuple. The first item is "span" string, and the other is a {'class' : 'a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal'} dictionary.